# What is the simplest way to open, modify and read the changes on a .txt file in Java?

Tags: java, file

I'm looking for a simple way to open a `.txt` file, **modify it** and read in real-time the changes applied on it.
I created a login panel, with two `JTextField` where user inserts ID/pass.

I want to implement a **change password method**, so I need to open the `.txt` file, delete the old password and write the new one (or overwrite). Then I have to read again the file to update the password.

That's the panel's code:

```
import static java.awt.Color.WHITE;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import linteati_ced.GUI.frame.MainFrame;
import linteati_ced.HotArea;
import static linteati_ced.utils.Constants.*;
import linteati_ced.utils.Resources;

public class LoginPanel extends JPanel {

    private MainFrame mf;

    private BufferedImage background;

    private FileReader file;
    private BufferedReader reader;

    private JTextField userArea, passwordArea;
    private String user, password;

    private HotArea confirm;
    private HotArea exit;
    private String message;

    private Thread dialogue;
    private String code;

    public LoginPanel(MainFrame mainFrame) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        this.setSize(PANEL_X, PANEL_Y);
        this.setLayout(null);

        this.mf = mainFrame;

        this.background = Resources.getImage(BACKGROUND_LOGIN);
        this.message = DEFAULT_MESSAGE;

        this.confirm = new HotArea(1178, 922, 60, 60);
        this.exit = new HotArea(1178, 25, 60, 60);

        this.file = new FileReader(Resources.extract(LOGIN));
        this.reader = new BufferedReader(file);

        this.userArea = new JTextField("");
        this.userArea.setBounds(600, 460, 200, 30);
        this.userArea.setFont(new Font("Arial", 0, 24));
        this.passwordArea = new JTextField("");
        this.passwordArea.setBounds(600, 550, 200, 30);
        this.passwordArea.setFont(new Font("Arial", 0, 24));

        this.add(this.userArea);
        this.add(this.passwordArea);

        try {
            this.user = reader.readLine();
            this.password = reader.readLine();
            this.code = reader.readLine();
            System.err.println(this.user);
            System.err.println(this.password);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }

        file.close();

        this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

                if (confirm.isClicked(e)) {
                    if (user.equals(userArea.getText()) && password.equals(passwordArea.getText())) {
                        mf.log_in();
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Error");
                        message = ERROR_MESSAGE;
                        dialogue = new Thread(new MessageDialogue());
                        dialogue.start();
                        repaint();
                    }
                }

                if (exit.isClicked(e)) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return this.code;
    }

    public void resetTextField() {
        this.userArea.setText("");
        this.passwordArea.setText("");
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, null);
        g.setColor(WHITE);
        g.setFont(new Font("Arial", 0, 22));
        g.drawString(message, 560, 660);
    }

    private class MessageDialogue implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1500);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }
            message = DEFAULT_MESSAGE;
            repaint();
        }

    }

}
```

These are the contents of the file.txt:
user
password

Comment: If you're modifying a file, you don't need to re-read it. You already know the modifications. Also there's really no such a thing as modifying a file. You can append to it, or you can fully overwrite it.

Comment: @Kayaman it's possible to overwrite parts of a file without needing to fully overwrite it.  It just isn't possible to delete or insert data, only change it.

Comment: Into the file.txt i have 2 words: one for user's id, one for user's password. 
I need to delete/overwrite the second line with the new password.

Comment: @puhlen Well yes, in a well defined binary format. That doesn't translate reliably to text files due to the line based format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your context:

```
Path path = Paths.get("... .txt");
List<String> = Files.readAllLines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
user = lines.get(0);
password = lines.get(1);
code = lines.get(2);

List<String> lines = new LinkedList<>();
Collections.addAll(lines, user, password, code);
Files.write(path, lines, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

You could also use .properties with key=value pairs, with a variant in XML form.

If you think of later changing your software with a new format, maybe a version number in the data would be nice too.

Answer (score 0):

When we are reading our file, we generally use String to store the contents of a file, but the problem is Strings are immutable that is they cannot be edited, but what you want to do could be done in this way :

1. When writing your password in a file try to write it in a separate one for the 
   sake of simplicity.
2. Then read that content and store it in a String variable.
3. Use replace method to change it.
4. and then rewrite that modified String on your file again.

Comment: And if above the above jargon isn't helpful, feel free to ask for an example code.

Comment: Yes excellent point... that is why databases are a blessing,  but if you want to store every user in single file then you have to use a condition for example, read the file till the specific username is reached... this could done by using hasNext() method of scanner, and a if condition which uses contains() method of String class.

Comment: you just deleted your comment -_-

Comment: i wrote a wrong thing: that's not quadratic relation (2^k) but 2k relation. Sorry for that

Comment: It is. I'll try it. Thank's!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to read the line of text from the file and, since you are using space delineation, split the string into an array using `string.split(" ")`. Update the password in `string[1]`, reform the string as `username password` and write it to the file using `FileOutputString(..., false) to overwrite the contents.

If you planned to leave the file open for periodic updates as needed, you could utilize a `RandomAccessFile` which maintains a pointer to the last `seek` and simply overwrite the password using `' '` to mask previous characters left behind from the previous password.

Either way, this is my suggestion but, as others pointed out already, for both security reasons and ease of maintenance, utilizing a database is far easier.  Where I worked, I had access to just such a database and was recently required to encrypt the passwords in the table.  This may be a desire of yours as well using cryptography.